# How to animate a slider(UIView) while switching pages inside an UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I want to implement something similar to Instagram activity screen header:

[image]

I added two buttons for Following and You which are insides an `UIView`(header). For the bottom blue bar I added an `UIView`.

Where exactly should I animate that `UIView` bar to move from Following to You screen when switching pages inside `UIPageViewController`?

Or maybe there is a better solution to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For something like this, I like using property observers to keep the API nice and clean for calling code.  In the following example I am doing just that and manually adjusting the frame values, but in practice you'll probably want to use Auto Layout and animate your constraints.

```
class MyHeader: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var selectionView: UIView!

    var buttons = [UIButton]()

    var selectedTabIndex: Int {
        didSet {
            UIView.animateWithDuration( 0.5) {
                let targetButton = self.buttons[ self.selectedTabIndex ]
                var frame = self.selectionView.frame
                frame.origin.x = targetButton.frame.minX
                frame.origin.y = targetButton.frame.maxY - frame.height
                frame.size.width = targetButton.frame.minX
                self.selectionView.frame = frame
            }
        }
    }
}
```